HTTP Error: 403, Permission 'firebasestorage.defaultBucket.get' denied on resource
I'm encountering an error when deploying to Firebase using the latest version of firebase-tools. The deployment was working fine previously, but now I'm getting a permission denied error related to the default storage bucket.
Environment:

firebase-tools: 13.15.2
Next.js: 14.1.4
Platform: Ubuntu (GitHub Actions)

Case:
I've started getting the following error when deploying to Firebase with the latest version
Unexpected error when fetching default storage bucket.
Error Message:
Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission 'firebasestorage.defaultBucket.get' denied on resource '//firebasestorage.googleapis.com/projects/myProjectId/defaultBucket' (or it may not exist). Reverting to 12.9.1 works fine.
Steps to Reproduce:
Running the following command:
firebase deploy --force --only hosting:dev,functions,firestore,storage --project my-project
What I've Tried:
I've checked the IAM and service account permissions in Firebase. The following roles are assigned:

Cloud Storage for Firebase Admin
Firebase Admin
Storage Admin

However, the issue persists despite these roles being assigned.
Additional Information:

Reverting to firebase-tools version 12.9.1 resolves the issue.
This problem seems to be related to the issue reported here: GitHub Issue #6593

Has anyone encountered this issue or know of a solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
What I've Tried:
I've checked the IAM and service account permissions in Firebase. The following roles are assigned:

Cloud Storage for Firebase Admin
Firebase Admin
Storage Admin

"I also ran a query in the Policy Analyzer, and it showed that the 'firebasestorage.defaultBucket.get' permission seems to be attached."
This additional information is valuable for troubleshooting your issue. It suggests that while the Policy Analyzer shows the required permission is present, there might be a discrepancy between what's shown there and what's actually being applied or recognized during the deployment process.
However, the issue persists despite these roles being assigned.
Additional Information:

Reverting to firebase-tools version 12.9.1 resolves the issue.
This problem seems to be related to the issue reported here: GitHub Issue #6593

Has anyone encountered this issue or know of a solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
